# Getting invalid crumb error even if crumb is valid

Tags: java, api, jenkins

I tried to trigger Jenkins build from rest API remotely. From last two weeks , i am getting crumb error as invalid crumb. Previously, it was working. also, when i tried to hit request from rest APi postman , i am getting valid crumb and i am passing crumb to trigger build, it successfully trigger Jenkins build. Same steps tried with rest API rest template, i am getting crumb error while triggering build. Can anyone please help me out.

Expected to trigger build.